# Is it possible to use AsyncTask in a Service class?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ui-thread

Everything is in the title.

On the official documentations it is stated that `Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process` and AsyncTask only works if it is executed in the UIThread.

So is it possible to use AsyncTask in a Service class?

I am trying to do so but I'm always getting the same error

```
05-01 18:09:25.487: ERROR/JavaBinder(270): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

...

```
05-01 18:09:25.487: ERROR/JavaBinder(270): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just impossible ?

Here is the code of my Service class

```
package com.eip.core;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class NetworkService extends Service {


    private final INetwork.Stub mBinder = new INetwork.Stub() {

        @Override
        public int doConnect(String addr, int port) throws RemoteException {
            new ConnectTask().execute("test42");
            return 0;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("OnPreExecute()", "");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Log.i("doInBackground()", "");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i("OnPostExecute()", "");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think I found why it is not working in my case.

Here I am using this :

```
private final INetwork.Stub mBinder = new INetwork.Stub() {

        @Override
        public int doConnect(String addr, int port) throws RemoteException {
            new ConnectTask().execute("test42");
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

I am using this to do what so called IPC, **Inter Process Communication**, so I guess that my Service and my Activity are in two differents process, AsyncTask must be executed in the main UI thread according to the android doc, so why I was trying to do seems to me just impossible according to those facts.

If I am wrong please someone can correct me.

Answer (score 12):

Also be sure to check out IntentService.  If that class is sufficient for your needs, it will take care of a lot of little details involved in making that pattern work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem is not AsyncTask but something else. For example are you sure your onBind method works correctly? Please try this:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

You could also try that

```
public class NetworkService extends Service{
  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    new ConnectTask().execute("test42");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use AsyncTask in a Service class?

Yes. See Reto Meier (2010) *Professional Android 2 Application Development*, Wrox. Meier has [published supporting code](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/27/04705655/DOWNLOAD/Professional%20Android%202%20Code%20Example%20Projects.zip) (see /Chapter 9 Earthquake 4/src/com/paad/earthquake/EarthquakeService.java):

```
public class EarthquakeService extends Service {        
    ... 
    private EarthquakeLookupTask lastLookup = null;
    ...

    private class EarthquakeLookupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Quake, Void> { 
        ... 
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {    
        ...
        refreshEarthquakes();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    };

    private void refreshEarthquakes() {
        ...
        lastLookup = new EarthquakeLookupTask();
        lastLookup.execute((Void[])null);
        ...
    }
}
```

On an aside, I cannot find any evidence to support your claim that "*AsyncTask only works if it is executed in the UIThread*" (although this would [violate threading rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172977/3664487)).

Comment: Hi it doesn't violate threading rules as your service always runs on UI thread till you don't fork threads from it

Comment: So the above code would work just fine i guess you are confused between services and intent services ,Intent services run in a background thread by default

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to [use `AsyncTask` in a `Service` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172917/3664487), this violates *threading rules*, in particular, `AsyncTask` must be instantiated and invoked on the UI thread. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172977/3664487 for further discussion.)