# android continuos polling ... how?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have an application that needs updating constantly. I would like to create a job (Service, thread ...?) that execute the polling over all the activities. I need to update some data even if i'm not on the activity that needs to.

I would not create a service because actually I don't need to update  tha application along it is closed. 
What do you suggest? 
Thanks
a.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What specifically are you trying to accomplish, please elaborate and be specific. also [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) with the data that it presents to the user. You do not mess with other activities that are not currently on screen.

If I understand correctly, you want to update some data that is shared among your activities whenever any activity is currently visible.

You could create a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which in turn uses a separate thread to do its polling. Then in each of your activities that you want the polling to be run you call `startService` in the `onResume` method of the activity and `stopService` in the `onPause` method of the activity.

Also make sure you use `return`[`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) at the end of your service's `onStartCommand` method.

Comment: A Service is definitely the way to go. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Comment: @Craigy Thanks for the reply, sorry i'ma a beginner. I try to be a little more specific.This is  a really simple application: there is a list of tasks that the user have to complete. Every task has a detail page. <br/><br/>I need to refresh the list also if the user is in the detail page (or other pages).<br/><br/>You suggest to use a service. Ok question, this server can be a AsyncTask? ... I try... thanks. a.

Comment: Sure, you can use an `AsyncTask` inside the service. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750664/is-it-possible-to-use-asynctask-in-a-service-class

Comment: Thank you! I've done... easier than I thought. One last thing, if I call the stopService on the onPause method of the List activity, when I call the Detail activity the service stops... ? And I need it alive...

Comment: Yes you will need to call `startService` in the `onResume` method of any activity where you want the polling to happen (and remember to put `stopService` in the `onPause` of that same activity).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I implemented in this way: I created a service which instantiates a TimerTask that makes the polling in the onCreate method and which stops the TimerTask in the onDestroy method. Then i put in all the activities the startService and the stopService respectively in the onResume and onPause method...

Comment: It wasn't better to have a unique entry point and a unique exit point of the service?