# How to call webservice from service in android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my application i need to call 4 web services at a time for every 2 minutes.I want's to call these web services form service.Can any one suggest me how to call these web service with best way.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Currently your question is to broad. what have you tried so far? where is the actual problem you cannot resolve? do you know how to call a soap/rest webservice? do you know how to execute code every 2 minutes? do you know how to implement a service? can you edit your question and add the missing detals? Otherwhise the question may be closed as beeing to broad.

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly creat a thread in service then u can use Asynctask in that
>   thread, but make sure u handling request in post method , on
>   DoInBackground method of AsyncTask u can call ur webservice functions. [here is the artical that worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750664/is-it-possible-to-use-asynctask-in-a-service-class)

Comment: Can you please provide any example.